# Magento2: Change layout of the Customer Registration page to 2columns-left

Tags: magento2, layout

I want to change to 2columns-left layout for the customer registration page. By updating `customer_account_create. xml` not solve my problem

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xml code :

> customer_account_create.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
       </body>
    </page>
```

Hope this will works.

Comment: is this different from my code?

Comment: @ketan I think you have not close page tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code :

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body/>
</page>
```